# Block access to a config file from external request but not internal in Apache2 Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, apache2, config, httpd.conf, virtual-hosts

so I have a config.json file which I want to block external connections for such as people accessing it directly, It's required for my script to run on so I want to whitelist only my own server which is hosting the file and not any external connections.

I tried this in my VirtualHost config but it doesn't seem to be working as it gives 403 forbidden error for even my script which is on the same server.

```
<Files config.json>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Files config.json>
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Order allow,deny
</Files>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, gives 403 Forbidden error even in my own script.

Comment: It works for me. What is the value of REMOTE_ADDR printed when the whole Files section is disabled?

Comment: What do you mean? How do I print that out?

Comment: Write a simple php script: `<?php var_dump($_SERVER); ?>`

Comment: Or look into apache access log.

Comment: Returned 141.101.xx.xx, Should I put that in Allow from?

Comment: Sure thing, fella.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, there is no authentication and all hosts in the 127.0.0.1 domain are allowed access; all other hosts are denied access.

2.2 configuration:

```
<Files config.json>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

2.4 configuration:

```
<Files config.json>
Require host 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

'...on the same server...' != `127.0.0.1`! I suspect your script is running on the same server but it does accesses the server process via public IP address.

If I'm right there are two possiblities.

- reconfigure your script to access via `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
- replace the address in the `Allow from` statement with the servers address